# Проблема с зависимостями пакетов в Linux Mint

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint

По не понятным мне причинам, на моей Linux Mint в 95 процентах случаев во время установки пакетов возникают проблемы с зависимостями. Сегодня не смог установить node.js, а вот что было после попытки обновить все пакеты:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как решать такие зависимости ?

Comment: То есть делали сначала обновление индекса пакетов -- sudo apt-get update ?

Comment: @JaponDemon да, перед этими командами запустил update

Comment: Сносите систему, самый простой способ решить проблему :)

Comment: @Антон  если по порядку sudo apt-get update, sudo apt-get upgrade, sudo apt-get autoremove, sudo apt-get autoclean,  sudo apt-get clean, sudo apt-get -f install и перезагрузить .?  Это всё делали?

Comment: написана же рекомендация: `$ apt-get -f install`

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: а ещё можно разрешить конфликт в полуручном режиме `aptitude`'ом... Вангую, что проблема связана с переходом дистра с мускуля на mariadb...